# Can I boot Ubuntu from a DVD and which version should I use?

Tags: boot

I have a Toshiba Satellite L455D-S5976 that had Win7 Premium installed. I did a “refresh” on the machine, and installed Win10. Then I left it alone for several weeks, went to start it and it wouldn’t recognize password or Identification answers.

I have used Ubuntu in the past but the only DVD I have is a Mac version. Can I download Ubuntu and copy it to a DVD? Bios will allow boot from DVD or HDD but not from a thumb drive. Any version?

Comment: Yes, you can burn an Ubuntu image to DVD,

Comment: With this old computer I suggest that you try an Ubuntu family flavour with a lighter footprint than standard Ubuntu - Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu. You can find the current iso files via [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Ubuntu releases use a *year.month* format, so Ubuntu 18.04 LTS means the 2018-April release of Ubuntu.  It was a LTS or long-term-support release, with 5 years of support for main server/desktop, but 3 years for any flavor (it was suggested a flavor Lubuntu or Xubuntu I agree with that has shorter 3 years). I tested Lubuntu 18.04 LTS & Xubuntu 18.04 LTS on ibm thinkpad t43, dell latitude d61 & other boxes from 2005 that came with XP.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-windows/14008
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-macos/14015
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/14022
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-verify-your-ubuntu-download/14010
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
(these apply equally to flavors; and CD in check refers to any media)
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Answer (score 0):

A DVD is a DVD is a DVD; all have the same formatting, whether created on/for a Mac, Windows PC, or Linux PC. What's *on* that DVD may be an Ubuntu installer that's fresh, or stale, but it's equally readable on all major operating systems.

The currently supported versions of Ubuntu and its flavours are 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, and 19.10.

Your Toshiba has an old AMD Sempron SI-42 (2.1 GHz) CPU and SATA-I (not SATA-III) drives, so with the standard 2 GB of DDR2 RAM, ATI Radeon 3100 GPU, and 802.11 b/g WiFi, you might find the standard Ubuntu 18.04 with its demanding GNOME3 Desktop Environment kinda poky.

Instead, https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours shows versions with different Desktop Environments which are less demanding (except for special distributions like Studio and Kylin). I'd suggest you consider one of those instead.

Once downloaded, that ISO file you use to create a LiveDVD should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Once verified, you can create a LiveDVD for testing and installation using [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#0), [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0), or [MacOS X](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#0).

Comment: i successfully burned a DVD and went to the laptop, changed bios to boot from DVD. started laptop and presumably installed my D/L of Xubuntu 18.04. Closed the laptop and removed DVD. Changed Bios back to boot from HDD and started the laptop again. All i got was a magnificent full screen rectangle (for a moment) then an error message telling me Windows hadn't loaded properly with two options troubleshoot Windows or restart Windows...neither of which helped Xububtu at all.sudodus and quiverc suggestions also helped.